# ICS file opened using Microsoft Outlook Desktop 2016's Calendar not honoring new lines in the Description body

Tags: outlook, ms-office, icalendar, vcalendar

As title states, when the ICS file below is opened using Microsoft Outlook Desktop 2016's calendar, the second to last new line (the "\n" before "lectus") in the Description body is not honored.  The word "lectus" remains on the same line as the text before it when the event is opened in Outlook's calendar.  This is obviously a contrived example but we are encountering this issue with other files.  The new lines are working fine, however, when using outlook web, yahoo calendar, and google calendar.  The file below is valid according to https://icalendar.org/validator.html.

Is anyone aware of a bug in Outlook 2016 desktop or am I missing something in the formatting of the file?

Thanks in advance.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//ABCD Corp//NONSGML My Product//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amett consectetur adipiscing elit just  
  Curabitur neque proiin\nUteauctor nibhiid quammmaximus rutrumn Sed egete
 Donec sit amet ultrices justoe suspendisse nec crase  integmalesuddanullo
 consequaturna\nlectus\n
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20220305
DTSTAMP:20220125T202911Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20220301
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Praesent in mauris eu tortor
UID:bac16d57-4606-4093-951a-1022b0587183
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**I included a snapshot below of what I'm talking about.  Notice the word "lectus" does not start on a new line.**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using an RTF markup instead? Or just replace `\n` with `\n\r` symbols. Have you tried to export an existing item with a proper markup and see how the field should look like?

Comment: I did try exporting an event from outlook.  The new lines were "\n" in the export.  The description in the exported file was not properly formatted when I saved the ICS file back to  the calendar.  It still did not honor the new lines.  The export did have a X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html property and when I left that in the file it did work.  However, I do not want to use HTML.  I want plain text only and I believe HTML is not a iCAL file standard and it may not be supported in other apps.

Answer (score 0):

The validators are not perfect or all encompassing.  Try check against as many as you can. eg http://ical-validator.herokuapp.com/?wicket:interface=:1::::  says

> ! CRLF should be used for newlines Related RFC 5545 section:
> 3.1

CRLF is  \r\n    (not \n\r)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CRLF

Comment: using \r\n instead of just \n results in double spacing in outlook for some reason. i'm looking for only single space.  and as mentioned in my comment above when I export from outlook they use \n for spacing.